# Inline code syntax highlighting in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

GitHub-flavored markdown supports [syntax highlighting in codeblocks](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#syntax-highlighting). This is done by adding the name of the language next to the triple-grave codeblock markers:

````markdown
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````

Standard markdown also supports inline codeblocks by wrapping text in `` `single graves` ``. Is there any way to add syntax highlighting to these inline codeblocks?

Comment: Assuming by "standard markdown," you mean CommonMark, the standard actually doesn't say anything about syntax highlighting. It just specifies how you can indicate something contains code.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**GitHub comments**, wikis, README.md etc. use [GFM, essentially CommonMark with some extensions](https://github.github.com/gfm/#code-spans), where **it's not possible** to add syntax highlighting. (Follow the link to see whether anything has changed, but don't hold your breath because nothing has in the last decade.)

However, **GitHub Pages** uses Jekyll and by extension [kramdown where you can use](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#span-ials):

```
`x = 4`{:.ruby}
```

P.S. If you happen to use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#verbatim), the syntax is:

```
`x = 4`{.ruby}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do

```
`(inline code)`{:.language-clojure .highlihgt}
```

for it to work, you have to add .highlight class too.
That only applies to Jekyll with kramdown.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible with Github Markdown:

I needed to do the same with an XML-structure inside a table row (in my case defined with markdown, nit html, so with | | delimitiers for the table structure)

just put the desired Style-class (in my case .language-xml) within the Structure {: }

```
`<xml attrib="someVal"></xml>`{:.language-xml}
```

this will set the style of the table cell to highlight the code according to the set style class

i guess for ruby it then will just be

```
{:.language-ruby}
```

took me over an hour to figure out, found the solution nowhere, so i thought i'd post it here if anyone stumbles upon this problem again.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, at least when commenting on github issues.

Comment: to be honest, i never tried to do it in Github comments.

i've done it with GuitHub flavoured Markdown and github pages, and there it works.

i've tried it just now on github issues. I couldn't find a fast way to make it work for github commenting... 

sorry that i could not help

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tested in both Gist and a README.md.