# Inline code syntax highlighting in Jupyter markdown?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It is possible to syntax highlight inline code in Jupyter?
Maybe similar as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226224/inline-code-syntax-highlighting-in-github-markdown).

Currently, the following markdown

````markdown
   Inline code `np.array`.
   vs.
   Code block:
   ```python
   np.array
   ```
````

yields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible; the `jupyter markdown` defines the triple quote followed by a language name as the "syntax highlighting markup".

It is not exactly what you want, but there are two ways to color text in a md cell:

**Using `LaTeX`:**

```tex
${\text{inline code :}}\color{red}{\text{ np.array}}{\text{ but no cigar}}$
```

**Using `HTML`:**

```html
inline code: <span style="color:red">np.array</span> but no cigar.
```

which respectively render like this:

[image]